# React.js 0.14 JSX Transform Replacement

Tags: reactjs

I'm going through some starter React.js courses to become more familiar with React, and the ES6 format. Unfortunately, the courses were created during 0.13 when the JSX Transformer was available, and I do not want to setup a node.js environment with each and every exercise file. It also seems that babel-browser was discontinued, and babel-standalone needs much more than a type in the script properties to compile, so neither seems to be a solution (Unless I misunderstood standalone).

Is there anything out there that handle transforms as simply as the JSX Transformer once did?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JSbin will transpile JSX and ES6 for you.  Just choose the ES6 / Babel setting on the JavaScript drop down.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about other sites. I know I could do similar with JSFiddle, and I have my own node.js react environments using browserify, and babel, but I'm really trying to find an answer for this particular issue. React devs claim that there are just as easy ways to accomplish this with babel, and the reason they continue to leave JSX Transformer, and react-tools out of releases.

Comment: Mind if I ask why 'no' to node? You don't have to "setup an environment" you just download node, clone a github repo that includes react-transform and you're done!

Comment: It's not a "no to node" situation. It's wanting to know what the replacement is, so that when wanting to write simple test scripts, I do not have to worry about setting up an entire environment for transforming.

Again, I have node environments, and I could move the files over, and have browserify/babel watch for changes, but when going through these courses where there are lots of different files, it's unrealistic to setup an environment for each one, or moving all of the files into a central location, after renaming them all.

Answer (score 1):

The react site tutorial (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) seems to use babel dynamically.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      // To get started with this tutorial running your own code, simply remove
      // the script tag loading scripts/example.js and start writing code here.
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha. I just saw that in the tutorial, and felt like a complete noob. Thanks for the answer to my question!